# Any way to add "All" to pageSizes array? Kendo UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am looking to add an option for "All" to the drop-down list of page sizes in the Kendo Web UI grid.

The pageSizes: property of .kendoGrid() will only accept integer arrays.

I've tried finagling the dropdown after grid init like so:

```
var testSelector = '.k-pager-sizes select[data-role="dropdownlist"]';
var test = $(testSelector).data('kendoDropDownList');

test.options.dataSource = [ 
  { value: 20, text: "20" }, 
  { value: 50, text: "50" }, 
  { value: 100, text: "100" }, 
  { value: 9007199254740992, text: "All" } 
];

test.options.dataTextField = "text";
test.options.dataValueField = "value";
test.refresh();
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Any help would be very... helpful. Thanks!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the page size and then refreshing the grid

```
 var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
          grid.dataSource.pageSize('some real big page size to simulate "all"')
          grid.dataSource.page(1) //refresh
```